# Hibernate foreign key not saved using @OneToOne notation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I couldn't store foreign  key in [ReservationHall] Entity :

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
Reservation reservation;
```

and I typed this in primary entity  [Reservation] :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="reservation",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
ReservationHall reservationHall;
```

After running data are coming to reservationHall but without key of reservation.

Comment: How does the key is provided to the entity?

Comment: using `<input class="input-md textinput textInput form-control"
              th:field="*{reservationHall.price}" 
              th:placeholder="#{e.rh.price}" style="margin-bottom: 10px" />`

see :  th:field="*{reservationHall.price}"

Comment: it's work by adding this line into service layer, But i think it's not logical :

`reservation.getReservationHall().setReservation(reservation);`

Comment: Why not if you are used a foreign key. On the other hand you can use One-to-one association that assumes both the source and target share the same primary key values.